# Center HStack content excluding content in VStack

Tags: swiftui, alignment, vstack, hstack

I have a pretty basic view with an `HStack`, that has an `Image`, `VStack`, `Text`, and another `Image` in it. What I would like for is the speedometer image, the `ProgressView` (which is in the `VStack`), the "75" text, and the chevron image to be centered horizontally. Maybe there is a better way to structure this, or some modifier I can apply that I'm not aware of. Again the goal is to have a horizontal row of content that is the `Image`, `ProgressView`, `Text` and an `Image` centered horizontally with the "Hello" text leading aligned to the `ProgressView`. Here is a screenshot of its current state and the code.

[image: Default font]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
            Image(systemName: "speedometer")
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Hello")
                ProgressView(value: 50, total: 100)
                    .progressViewStyle(.linear)
            }
            Text("75")
            Image(systemName: "chevron.forward")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This is what I want the alignment to look like. What is missing from this screenshot is I want the text "Hello" to be above the `ProgressView`, and leading aligned:

[image: HStack]

Comment: have you tried to just remove the `VStack`. Do you have a picture of what you want to achieve. The way I read your description, is that you want everything on one line.

Comment: I realize now my phrasing was poor. In the screenshot there are 2 "rows". The first row being the text "Hello", and the second row being everything else. I want everything else to be centered horizontally.

Comment: I have updated to include another screenshot hopefully clarifying what I'm looking for.

Comment: looks like you want to move the `VStack` just a little bit up.
 If so, try attaching something like `.offset(x: 0, y: -5)` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be a number of ways to achieve this layout. Techniques at your disposal include:

- use `.padding` to shift items into position
- use `.offset` to tweak positions
- use fixed sizes for the items
- use an `.alignmentGuide`
- use overlays
- use hidden content to reserve space
- change the `.baselineOffset` for the `Text`
- change the alignment of the stacks.

Here is a variation that uses a `VStack` containing two `HStack`. If the size of the speedometer image would be known then padding could be used to reserve this space. Since it is not known, a hidden version of the image is used instead:

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "speedometer")
            .hidden()
        Text("Hello")
    }
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "speedometer")
        ProgressView(value: 50, total: 100)
            .progressViewStyle(.linear)
        Text("75")
        Image(systemName: "chevron.forward")
    }
}
.padding()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I found using the `.hidden()` modifier to be the best for my use case. Thank you for your feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a bit more complex than it appears at first - since you essentially want to insert an extra view (Text) into your aligned layout without affecting it.

Off of my head, you can try the following, progressively hacky solutions:

1. Use a grid
2. Bottom alignment for HStack, defining same height for the 3 aligned elements (you can define a view’s alignment in its own frame using something like: .frame(height: Foo, alignment: .center)
3. Force the SwiftUI layout to ignore the Text by setting its height to 0
4. GeometryReader